# How to recover files from filesystem converted from ntfs to ext4 using Ubuntu live CD

Tags: dual-boot, mount, live-usb, data-recovery

I just convinced one artist to install Ubuntu, invited to the open source sphere. He agreed to come along. And I advised him to install Ubuntu along with his Windows installation.

I mistakenly deleted his C drive and converted to ext4. That made two partitions one is free space and other is the ext4 partition. I need to recover his documents, his artworks, videos, and other files on C drive using Ubuntu liveboot. I tried with `testdisk`.

Any other options or suggestions.

Comment: ok. Is there any help using `photorec`

Comment: Photorec is a file carver, it does not perform directory tree reconstruction and it cannot work with fragmented files. It doesn't make sense to start with a file carver without trying other options.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto that's not a good dupe target for this question. From OPs description It seems they already formatted the NTFS partition to ext4.

Comment: @Anwar, do not look only at the title, but at the actual answer as well.

Comment: @AndreaLazarotto I read both the title and body of the question. And FYI, same answer doesn't mean same question.

Comment: @Anwar, it has been discussed on meta multiple times here and on other communities. Many times, it does. Anyway the answer there fits the situation of the OP and that's the main goal (I mean solving the actual problem).